# How do i save as pdf via VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code, where I want to:

1. Save Masterfile (current active workbook),
2. amend the workbook and delete sheets,
3. then save separate copies of the edited workbook
   as an Excel sheet and a PDF file.

The problem I have here is that the code saves the PDF file as the original Masterfile even after I have tried to activate the edited Excel file. Any help here? Would really appreciate any advice! Code below:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Save


Sheets("Inventory").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Cells.Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Sheets("May").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Cells.Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

Range("A1").Select
Sheets("Macro").Select
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Sheets("Oct").Select
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Sheets("Inventory").Select
Range("A1").Select

Sheets("Inventory").Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 0

ChDir "G:\9Fixed\Posi\2016\Inventory"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "G:\9Fixed\Posi\2016\Inventory\Asia Fixed - " & Format(Date, "dd mmm") & ".xls", FileFormat:= _
    xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'ActiveWorkbook.ExclusiveAccess
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Workbooks("Asia  - " & Format(Date, "dd mmm") & ".xls").Activate
ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
"G:\9Fixed Income\Positions\2016\Inventory\Asia Fixed Income - " & Format(Date, "dd mmm") & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not reproduce the issue you were having.

Here is my 'test' code, using a workbook with 4 sheets and information in cells(1,1), one sheet named "May" --- which is deleted, and the new file does not have "May" and the pdf does not either.

I moved the saveas code towards the top of the file. Maybe that will fix your issue, but I don't believe it will.

```
Option Explicit
Sub SaveCopies()
    Dim c_OUTPUTDIR As String
    Dim sFileName As String
    Dim fso As Object ' Used to handle paths, filenames, etc.
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    c_OUTPUTDIR = "C:\temp\"
    ' Save the master copy.
    ActiveWorkbook.Save


    ' Generate new name for file.
    sFileName = fso.GetBaseName(ActiveWorkbook.FullName) & "_" & Format(Date, "dd mmm")
    ' Save new working file.
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        c_OUTPUTDIR & sFileName & ".xls", FileFormat:= _
        xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

    ' Make changes to working file.
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("May").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    ' Save the changes.
    ActiveWorkbook.Save

    ' Save a PDF of the file.
    ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    c_OUTPUTDIR & sFileName & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: I'll try your code, and thanks for getting back to this question! However can i ask, why do you save a new copy of the file first before editing it and then saving it again?

Comment: Personal preference to ensure I never overwrite the master copy with edits :)